# PHP cURL request changes POST data

Tags: php, post, curl, firebug

I have a problem with my POST request using the PHP cURL module. I have a string `$new_post` like this (cropped here because it's too long):

```
    $new_post = '...AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView$RadioButtonMarketStructure='.$tipe.'&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView$DropDownListMarketDay1='.$tanggal1.'&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView$DropDownListMarketMonth1='.$bulan1.'&date_picker='.$bulan1.'-'.$tanggal1.'&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView$DropDownListMarketDay2='.$tanggal2.'&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView$DropDownListMarketMonth2='.$bulan2.'&date_picker='.$bulan2.'-'.$tanggal2.'&...;
```

When I post that using `curl_exec` the POST string gets changed by itself. The substring `AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView` changes into `AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView`. I checked it with Firebug.

I don't know why that happens. Can anyone tell me why it can be like that? Here's my code for the request:

```
    $data = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 180);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $new_post);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,0);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
    curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0");
    $result = curl_exec($data);
```

*Edit

This is what exactly the right post if i do in the real webpage. I trying to post the same way. I am sorry i can upload the screenshot of my firebug because i don't have enough reputation.

__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUBMGRkBsrCYiDYbQKCOcoq%2FUTudEf14vk%3D&pageToken=&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectVieworiginStation1=&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24TextBoxMarketOrigin1=&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectViewdestinationStation1=&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24TextBoxMarketDestination1=&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectVieworiginStation2=&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24TextBoxMarketOrigin2=&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectViewdestinationStation2=&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24TextBoxMarketDestination2=&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24RadioButtonMarketStructure=RoundTrip&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24DropDownListMarketDay1=14&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24DropDownListMarketMonth1=2014-04&date_picker=2014-04-14&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24DropDownListMarketDay2=21&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24DropDownListMarketMonth2=2014-04&date_picker=2014-04-21&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24DropDownListPassengerType_ADT=3&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24DropDownListPassengerType_CHD=0&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24DropDownListPassengerType_INFANT=0&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24DropDownListSearchBy=columnView&AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView%24DdlCurrencyDynamic=IDR&ControlGroupScheduleSelectView%24AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView%24HiddenFieldTabIndex1=4&ControlGroupScheduleSelectView%24AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView%24market1=0%7EP%7E%7EP%7ERGFR%7E%7E1%7EX%7CQG%7E+853%7E+%7E%7EDPS%7E04%2F22%2F2014+20%3A05%7ECGK%7E04%2F22%2F2014+20%3A50%7E&ControlGroupScheduleSelectView%24AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView%24HiddenFieldTabIndex2=4&ControlGroupScheduleSelectView%24AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView%24market2=0%7EQ%7E%7EQ%7ERGFR%7E%7E1%7EX%7CQG%7E+852%7E+%7E%7ECGK%7E04%2F23%2F2014+16%3A40%7EDPS%7E04%2F23%2F2014+19%3A30%7E&ControlGroupScheduleSelectView%24ButtonSubmit=Lanjutkan

Comment: Firebug just displays requests done by the browser. It cannot track requests done on the server side. So you may add a screenshot of what you see there.

Comment: It's too long. but if you want to see what my browser post to the webpage, that's all.

Comment: I assume the above is what you see within Firebug's [*Net* panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel) when you expand the request and switch to the *Post* tab within it, right? So where do you actually see the incorrect `AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView` data? Do you output the data somewhere within the PHP script that processes the data?

Comment: Yes, that is what actually i see in Firebug's Net Panel Post tab when i try with the true URL (https//:www.xxx.com/xxx for example). I see `AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView` when my localhost sent POST data to the URL (https://localhost/test2.php) and i inspect it also with firebug. when i use `echo` to check my variable, the value still same.

Comment: I think I know why my post in Firebug's net panel didn't match with the variable `$new_post`. maybe because I post from one page to another page in my localhost. that mean the Post i seen in firebug's net panel not what my _php curl_ post. is that any may to check what i post with my _php curl_ same with the one that i want to post?

Comment: Yes, using a browser independent network analyzer tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) you're able to see all the network traffic. Though note using it to track requests on your local machine (which doesn't really create network traffic) requires some [special setup](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not see the cURL request within Firebug, because it happens on the server.

> I see AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView when my localhost sent POST data to the URL (localhost/test2.php) and i inspect it also with firebug.

If you see `AvailabilitySearchInputSearchView` just within Firebug but get the correct POST body when you `echo` it within the PHP script you call through `curl_exec()`, your problem is unrelated to the cURL request.

Comment: If my answer was appropriate to solve your problem, you may upvote or accept it. You may also want to update your question to clarify the problem further, so people can give better answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use `http_build_query()` before passing it to `curl_setopt()`, like this:

```
$post = array('foo'=>'bar',
              'baz'=>'boom',
              'cow'=>'milk',
              'php'=>'AvailabilitySearchInputScheduleSelectView$RadioButtonMarketStructure');

$post  = http_build_query($post);

$data = curl_init();
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 180);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,0);
curl_setopt($data, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($data, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:28.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/28.0");
$result = curl_exec($data);
```

Comment: The strings within the `$new_post` variable are surrounded by single quotes, so the `$` sign is not interpreted.

Comment: @SebastianZartner You're right, I forgot about that.

Comment: what the is the sign is not interpreted? is that doesn't matter with my post or what? please tell me. @SebastianZartner

Comment: @hkjhj The sign was the dollar sign. Tuga already removed the sentence related to it again from his/her answer.